# Nondimensionalising a second order differential equation modelling a horizontal mass-spring system (friction force included) a specific way

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

There is a differential equation $$m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t) = -c\frac{d}{dt}x(t) - kx(t) , \qquad \textrm{where} \quad c, k, m \ge 0 .$$ It is supposed to model a spring, where $k$ is the spring constant, $c$ is the coefficient of friction, and $m$ is the mass attached to the spring. We assume $$x(0)= 0 \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \frac{d}{dt}x(0) = v ,$$ where v is a constant $\ge 0$. The task is to nondimensionalise the initial value problem by choosing appropriate scales for time and displacement such that the outcome is of the form
$$
  \frac{d^2}{d\tilde{t}^2} \tilde{x}(\smash{\tilde{t}})
+ \frac{d  }{d\tilde{t}  } \tilde{x}(\smash{\tilde{t}})
+ \tilde{k}\,              \tilde{x}(\smash{\tilde{t}})
= 0$$
where
$$\tilde{x}(0) = 0, \qquad \frac{d}{d\tilde{t}}\tilde{x}(0) = 1, \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \tilde{k} > 0 .$$ It is also mentioned that $\tilde{k}$ is to be expressed in terms of the other parameters. The reason I am finding this so difficult is because I have no idea how to change both the $c$ and the $m$ into 1s. Differentiating would not be able to discriminate between the two, so how does one go about this?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477173/damped-driven-oscillator-dimensional-analysis

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Scaling the dependent variable $x$ scales all derivatives of $x(t)$ by the same factor, but scaling the independent variable $t$ scales the derivatives of different orders differently: If $\tau = \frac{t}{t_0}$ and $\xi = \frac{x}{x_0}$, then the Chain Rule gives $$\frac{d^k}{dt^k} x(t) = \frac{x_0}{t_0^k} \frac{d^k}{d\tau^k} x(\tau) ,$$
so transforming the differential equation thusly yields
$$\frac{m x_0}{t_0^2} \xi''(\tau) + \frac{c x_0}{t_0} \xi'(\tau) + k x_0 \xi(\tau) = 0 ,$$
and the initial conditions
$$\xi(0) = x(0) = 0 \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \xi'(0) = \frac{t_0 v}{x_0} .$$
Now, choose $x_0, t_0$ and scale the differential equation to satisfy normalized conditions.